# Is REST a good approach for developing a video playback api?

Tags: rest, video-streaming, backend

We want to create a video playback backend (think about youtube, pluralsight). Is there a better architecture for delivering video content to the front-end than REST(keeping in mind buffering, closed captions, letting the user continue his video from where he left)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell you what I did when I have to stream a video. I am talking specifically about Java spring. [Java Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) supports video streaming. You can create a video store backed by file system by using Spring content for file system. Put your video(s) in that store and by using Spring Content Rest it will will serve over HTTP to any front-end player.